# Tradingview grab indicators value

Tags: tradingview-api

I setup some webhooks on tradingview to hit my API. What I would like to do, if possible, is include in the alert in the body of the webhook, the current value or whichever indicator I am using. E.g. Stoch RSI, TMA Divergence, etc.

Is this possible at all? I know i can setup alerts on the indicators themselves, but that's not really what I need. I wanna lookup what those indicator values are when a certain price is hit and i get my notification.

Would love if someone can help out with this :)

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you include those values in the alert message?

Comment: because you can't? and that's pretty much the essence of my question. found a better way tho.. thanks.

Comment: Well, you sure can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Found a better way since you can't seem to be able to do that.

I just send custom indicators alerts at certain intervals, store the values and look them up when a certain price is then reached.

Hope it helps someone else

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).